# Is it possible to call a function defined in main.rs from lib.rs?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to call a function defined in `main.rs` (like `main` itself) from `lib.rs`? If yes, how? The only information that I found was this from more than a year ago:

> However it does appear that the importing behavior doesn't work the
> other way. I.e. if you declare some public module in src/main.rs, you
> can't import it into the src/lib.rs crate even when you specify the
> name of the crate. I couldn't find documentation describing this
> behavior but by testing it in Rust 1.37.0, it does appear to be the
> case.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't import from binary crates at all.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to call `main()` _from_ a function in a lib? Or do you have both a `lib.rs` and a `main.rs` in the same project?

Comment: I was thinking about calling main.rs or any function that is written in main.rs inside lib.rs

Comment: No that's not possible. However you can put everything in the library and only have a minimal `main.rs` that only calls the top-level library function.